# Problem with jQuery toggle on 2 objects in IE8

Tags: html, hyperlink, jquery

I've got an expanding section on a web page, and I'm using jQUery to create the "expand/collapse" links that, on-click, will toggle each other.  It's working in every browser except IE8.  In fact, it works perfectly when IE8 is in Compatibility Mode.

What is supposed to happen is that when you click "Expand", the expandable section will slide down and the "Expand" link toggles to "display:none" while the "Collapse" link toggles to "display:inline".  This works.  However, when you click the "Collapse" link, the "Expand" link never reappears (***only in IE8***):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Toggle Link Test</title>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.search_link').click(function(){
        $('.search_link').toggle();
        $('#toggle_div').slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Search
        <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="search_link" style="display: inline;">Collapse [-]</a>
        <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="search_link" style="display: none;">Expand [+]</a>
    </legend>
    <div id="toggle_div">
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
        <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you have an orphan `</style>` under your `<title>` element.

Comment: Works fine when I test in IE8 using this - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/b8BFb/

Comment: Sorry the `</style>` was because of a copy and paste mistake.  I was removing the styling for simplicity. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Dexter: Upgrade your version of jQuery. Anything less than 1.4.4 seems to exhibit the problem you're describing (tested in IE8 with jsFiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/3KxwC/).

Comment: Thanks, upgrading fixed the problem.   I remember reading something in the documentation about <a> tags and an apparent bug with the "inline" trait, but I couldn't find it, so I couldn't determine if it was related.  Thanks again.